# measuring capacitors

Tags: capacitor

I have a multimeter which does not include capacitor checking facility. So, the method I am doing to check capacitor is, that, first I connect it with a battery for some seconds and check the voltage across the capacitor. If the votage is same as the emf of battery, then I conclude that the capacitor is working. But my friend says that this is not a suitable method, as the voltage is not same as capacitance. But I argue that this only the test for working of capacitor, and if it works properly, then the capacitance should be equal to the quantity that labelled on it. But he disagree me without reason.

Is my method is wrong? Then how I detect failure of capacitors?

Comment: You can use series RC circuit to test it.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the nominal capacitance, and you have *just* a multimeter and some resistors, then you can measure (within perhaps 10%), but you will need a separate voltage source with known voltage.

Choose a resistor such that C (your capacitance) times the resistor is about 5 seconds. The time to charge the capacitor to 63% is R * C.

Connect the resistor and capacitor in series and connect the multimeter across the capacitor in volts mode. When you are all set, connect the external power source (be careful not to exceed the rating of your capacitor).

The voltage across the capacitor will rise, and take a measurement at 63% (at whatever R * C came out to) of the external voltage source recording the time taken.

The capacitor has a value of time (recorded) / R, as this time is equal to nominal R * C.

Good if you have limited tools and need a rough and ready measurement.